# Custom defined column name for JSONObject key

Tags: java

I have a JSONObject in which I am putting keys and values from columns in my database. I want the key name to show up as a custom defined name, while I have it equivalent to the column name in the DB. How do I do this?

For eg, I have -

```
    myObj.put(resultSet.getString(personId), personCarInfo);
```

While I want it to be -

```
    myObj.put("personId", personCarInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JDBC, you can query the name of a column using the `ResultSet`s meta data:

```
String columnName = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(columnIndex);
String columnValue = resultSet.getString(columnIndex); // assuming, its a string
myObj.put(columnName, columnValue);
```

Comment: How do I display this column name as my JSONObject key?

Comment: I've extended the sample code above (assuming that personId is the index of the person column in the result set).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have mapping between `column names` and your `custom defined names`. 
You could create simple one-directional mapping using statically initialized `hashMap` or by using `enums`.
If you want bi-directional mapping (i.e. be able to restore your table `column name` string from custom `"personId"` string) you could use Guava [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), for example.
Hope that helps.